# I don't want to let my friends down

Tags: cipher, knowledge, word-search, meta-knowledge

<sub>This is an entry into the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #36](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6372/fortnightly-topic-challenge-36-twisted-classics-1)</sub>

I was supposed to do something, but I can't remember what it was. I know it was supposed to be fun or funny. In a typical effort to hide my plans from my friends, I made a word search that was scrambled using a Keyword Cipher. It seems; however, that I've forgotten what the Keyword was. I know it has something to with roll, but that isn't it. Rock and roll? Sick role? Kick and roll? Duck roll? Maybe you can help me remember. I do remember the keyword is a four letter word.

> `K   Y   X   L   I   P   K   R   K   W   O   C   E   A   T
>
>   D   I   E   E   L   D   U   R   L   Z   S   R   S   H   T
>
>   Q   B   T   Y   K   D   B   Z   M   M   J   P   Y   Z   L
>
>   F   S   S   B   K   U   O   R   D   M   P   Z   H   I   X
>
>   M   A   V   A   Q   F   Z   U   K   L   N   E   O   O   M
>
>   U   U   D   E   N   G   B   M   G   Z   B   D   U   Z   T
>
>   F   F   Y   Z   A   C   M   I   O   H   U   A   R   O   I
>
>   O   I   X   N   Q   I   P   H   A   E   V   A   K   S   L
>
>   Y   A   F   V   J   F   U   K   V   A   B   F   A   A   B
>
>   E   X   G   G   W   V   J   N   F   N   R   N   G   Q   T
>
>   R   J   A   E   O   C   F   N   D   B   U   Z   S   E   N
>
>   Y   L   Y   J   D   A   P   H   W   B   J   Q   Y   I   D
>
>   R   P   N   F   E   S   C   W   B   T   K   U   X   I   U
>
>   J   L   Y   F   P   P   E   E   H   Q   K   G   R   G   H
>
>   O   C   X   Z   C   U   N   Y   A   R   W   Q   Y   R   X`

What activity was I planning to do with my friends?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You planned to

> **RICKROLL** your friends.
> That's why your plans are secret, as rickrolling requires deception.

Using the key:

> RICK

produces:

> `dyxmbqdadwpchet
> gbhhmguAmzsaskt
> rftydgfzNnlqyzm
> issfdupagNqzkbx
> NEVERizudmOhPpn
> uughojfnjzfGUzt
> iiyzecnbpkueapb
> pbxorbqkEhvedsm
> yeivliudVefieef
> hxjjwvloIoaojrt
> alehpcioGfuzsho
> ymylgeqkwflrybg
> aqoihscwftduxbu
> lmyiqqhhkrdjajk
> pcxzcUOYeawryax`
>
> Words found:
> NEVER
> GONNA
> GIVE
> YOU
> UP(ambiguous?, could go up+right instead of straight up)

Also fits the title:

> "Never gonna give you up.  Never gonna let you down"

Comment: That's right so far, but what does it all mean? Also, you may want to list out the words, as well them showing them in the word search.

Comment: I'm guessing the "activity" involves either the [Half-Life 3 announcement](https://youtu.be/5nHKN2cqONY) or [Oregon Politics](https://youtu.be/fZi4JxbTwPo)

Comment: @DavidStarkey Now that's an idea I would run with.

Comment: Based on all the above, maybe the thing you were supposed to do was simply to rot13(evpx-ebyy fbzrobql)?

Comment: @DavidStarkey I couldn't lock down a specific instance of it to roll with, but those are good examples, thanks.  If it's beyond my vague answer, you should post your own...it won't make me cry.

Comment: @Mohirl Thanks, I went ahead and added that.  I didn't come out and say it, as I didn't think the keyword would literally be the activity.  Oh, and thanks for not deserting me.

Comment: @hagfy Yeah, it seems a bit too obvious!

Comment: This is correct, so you can update to a full answer now. I wanted the puzzle to not be too difficult, because of the cipher.